# How to extract Polygons from Multipolygons in Shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

I'm trying to extract the polygons from multipolygons in Shapely. I can transform a list of polygons into multipolygons using `MultiPolygon` from Shapely.

```
>>> Multi = MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in fiona.open('data.shp')])
```

And,

```
>>> Multi.wkt
'MULTIPOLYGON (((249744.2315302934148349 142798.1643468967231456, 250113.7910872535139788 142132.9571443685272243, 250062.6213024436729029 141973.7622582934272941, 249607.7787708004761953 141757.7120557629095856, 249367.7742475979903247 142304.6840291862317827, 249367.7742475979903247 142304.6840291862317827, 249744.2315302934148349 142798.1643468967231456)), 
               ((249175.7899173096520826 142292.5352640640921891, 249367.7742475979903247 142304.6840291862317827, 249607.7787708004761953 141757.7120557629095856, 249014.4539607730694115 141876.1348429077770561, 249175.7899173096520826 142292.5352640640921891)))'
```

Does anybody know how can I reverse the process i.e. given a multipolygon how can I convert it to separate polygons?

Comment: Did you try `polygons = [polygon for polygon in Multi]`?

Comment: I tried your solution but i had this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. You have an idea ?

Answer (score 36):

Simply do

```
Polygons = list(Multi)
```

This extracts the polygons and puts them in a list.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable` when using this.
I tried `list(gdf['geom'].iloc[0].geoms)` and it worked for me

Comment: for shapely 2.0+  `list(Multi.geoms)` works

Answer (score 25):

To avoid Deprecation Warning when using [this othwerwise ok answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224866/8565438), do:

```
Polygons = list(Multipolygon.geoms)
```

Comment: When using Shapely 2.0 this is the correct answer

Answer (score 20):

According to [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#collections) on collections, which include such classes as `MultiPoint`, `MultiLineString` and `MultiPolygon`, their members can be "*accessed via the `geoms` property or via the iterator protocol using `in` or `list()`*":

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon

multipolygon = MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]),
                             Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])])

polygons = list(multipolygon)
print(*polygons)
# POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)) POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))

polygons = list(multipolygon.geoms)
print(*polygons)
# POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)) POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))

for polygon in multipolygon:  # same for multipolygon.geoms
    print(polygon)
# POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
# POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
```

You can also extract individual geometries by their index:

```
print(multipolygon[0])
POLYGON ((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
```

Slicing them will give you a collection though:

```
print(multipolygon[:1])
MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)))
```

Comment: As of version 2.0.1, this answer is unfortunately no longer correct. The [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/manual.html#collections) states "Members of a *GeometryCollection* are accessed via the `geoms` property."

Answer (score 1):

As other have already noted from shapely 1.8 onwards iterating upon the Multipolygon class is deprecated. The following code will work in 1.8 but won't in 2.0.

```
for poly in multipolygon:
  print(poly)
```

The correct way of doing it since 2.0 as follows:

```
for poly in multipolygon.geoms:
  print(poly)
```

Also if you are not specifically iterating through the polygons it might have to do with other libraries being outdated and calling a shapely 2.0 version.